# Hacking IKEA table - OR gate needed

Tags: resistors, diodes

I am working on modifying electric old IKEA Galant table(that's the only label i can find on it, it's a pretty old model. And it is surely not IKEA Bekant which has more resources available online). I would need some help to simulate button presses using microconroller(ESP32).

Basically, the table has two buttons - up and down. Whenever the button is pressed it pulls down to GND and the table moves (as on a schematic below). It is about 5V logic sitting on the button before it's pressed.

So I'm thinking about adding a microcontroller which will simply pull down to GND whenever the table needs to be moved. On the picture below two little gray lines are indicating where the microcontroller's pins would connect.

My problem or lack of knowledge is how to add that microcontroller connection? Should it be behind the diode (since microcontroller has it's own ~5V), or should there be any pull up resistors to make sure the mcu doesn't trigger low signal whenever powered up or down?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Updated**:

I have some IRLD120 MOSFETs lying around, so here is updated full diagram of my "kitchen" with MOSFET as Tom has recommended:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a proper schematic or block diagram and details of your actual setup?

Comment: @vtolentino, i have just updated the description with the schematic

Comment: I see a cartoon photograph and not a schematic circuit diagram. What is *electric IKEA Galant table*?

Comment: That's not a schematic diagram.  It is a wiring diagram.  It shows where the wires are connected, but provides no information about what each connection actually does.

Comment: @IljaLeiko have you got the right name?  When I look up Galant I find cabinets.  Electrically-raised desks appear to be called Bekant https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/bekant-desk-sit-stand-black-stained-ash-veneer-black-s89282218/

Comment: @jonathanjo, i'm pretty sure, at least that's the only label i can find on it. I got this table second hand, so i would assume it's been on a market a few years ago and the model is probably discontinued by now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is to use an N-Ch MOSFET to simulate a push button operation.

With the source connected to GND, the drain connected to the button, then the gate becomes an electrically controlled push button. This is a classic open-drain output circuit. As a circuit it should work to interface with most circuits that use a push-button-to-ground approach.

You can drive the MOSFET gate with anything, like your MCU output. A pull-down resistor (from gate to source) would be a good addition to prevent the MOSFET turning on when the MCU pins are high impedance.

The reason for this suggestion is two-fold:

1. Differences in IO voltages between your microcontroller and the other circuit will not have any impact as the MCU pin is not directly driving the circuit.
2. You can still push the existing button to control the table without risking damage if the MCU output was ever set high.

Comment: This is a good solution, please note that the ESP runs from 3.3V, so driving something that needs 5V could sometimes work, but not a perfect solution (your pins need to be 5V tolerant for a start). Common ground and powering the board needs to be solved, maybe there is a 5V supply somewhere for the on-board LDO? Using tiny relays or photocouplers instead would give some isolation as well.

Comment: Thank you, Tom an Nyos for awesome ideas. I will try to draft a simple schematic(not a diagram this time, haha) for that and get back to this thread with implementation of your proposed solution. :) Thank you both

Comment: @Tom Carpenter, I have now updated the thread description with a new design using MOSFET i have around. Would you please take a look if my proposed design would work? Thanks a lot

Comment: @IljaLeiko only thing I'd add is a 10k resistor from gate to ground on both MOSFETs

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much @TomCarpenter. Updated the descr and accepted the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In a YouTube video on [IKEA Bekant Table Hacking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AB75AxprXqQ), its author says (8m48s) the buttons of the table's board are "pulled up by resistors and shorted to ground when the button is pressed". He continues to say that he connects those directly to the output from a microcontroller (ATmega 328 at 5V.)

All the complexity of that project is due to parsing packets which give the current height.  The output which simulates the button pushes is entirely straightforward.

All of his details are here https://github.com/robin7331/IKEA-Hackant including schematic of ATmega controller and close-up photos of board being interfaced to.

A quick look at the code shows straightforward `OUTPUT` configuration for each pin: I would have expected only driving it low; but you can certainly see the operation working in the video.

Comment: Thank you, @jonathanjo, for the awesome resource. 
That could be a next project, once i upgrade to IKEA Bekant type of table with "LIN" communication as the author of the video shows. That would be a next level. For now what i have on hands is a simple and old-style IKEA table which has all it's circuitry hidden together with an actuator and power supply in one black box. Not really into hacking that one yet, so what i have got on my hands is simply two buttons with i would connect to in parallel and implement NMOS as Tom has described to simulate button press.